# Grouping 'like' rows in SQL and summing?

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, reporting-services

I have a report that looks like this:

[image: Report]

Notice the rows that I have circled (row 2 and 3 in the 1109 group).  These rows have the same MemberSep, Location, and Consumer text.  The only difference is they each have different values for the TODKWH001 and TODKWH002 fields.

What I'd like to do is group rows like this together and sum the TODKWH001 and TODKWH002 fields together.

So, instead of these two rows:

```
00002574027 00000003105401 YEAGER FMS PMP 50 13 00    0      1
00002574027 00000003105401 YEAGER FMS PMP 50 13 00 4998     81
```

I'd have just one row:

```
00002574027 00000003105401 YEAGER FMS PMP 50 13 00 4998     82
```

Can I do this in SQL?  Or should I try to do the grouping in my report?

Also, here is my SQL that I use to populate the report now:

```
SELECT CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.MBRSEP, 
       CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.LOCATION, 
       CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.BILLTYPE, 
       CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.BILLMOYR, 
       CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.RATE, 
       CAR1.CAV_LOCINFODETL.DIST, 
       CAR1.CAV_DEMANDHISTDETL.TODKWH_001, 
       CAR1.CAV_DEMANDHISTDETL.TODKWH_002, 
       CAR1.CAV_LOCINFODETL.ADDR1, CAR1.CAV_DEMANDHISTDETL.READTYPE
FROM CAR1.CAV_LOCINFODETL, { oj CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL LEFT OUTER JOIN
     CAR1.CAV_DEMANDHISTDETL ON CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.MBRSEP = 
     CAR1.CAV_DEMANDHISTDETL.MBRSEP AND 
     CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.BILLMOYR = CAR1.CAV_DEMANDHISTDETL.BILLMOYR }
WHERE CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.LOCATION = CAR1.CAV_LOCINFODETL.LOCATION AND
    (CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.BILLMOYR IN ('1104', '1105', '1106', '1107', '1108','1109')) AND
    (CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.RATE = '0096') AND (CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.BILLTYPE IN ('00', '01'))
ORDER BY CAR1.CAV_LOCINFODETL.DIST, 
         CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.BILLMOYR, 
         CAR1.CAV_MBRHISTDETL.MBRSEP
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Work this into your current query:

```
SELECT MemberSep, Location, Consumer, SUM(TODKWH001), SUM(TODKWH002)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY MemberSep, Location, Consumer
```

Comment: This looks exactly like what I need.  Thank you so much!